# iptables -P FORWARD DROP makes port forwarding slow

Tags: iptables

I have three computers, linked like this:

```
box1 (ubuntu)   box2 router & gateway (debian)       box3 (opensuse)
[10.0.1.1] ---- [10.0.1.18,10.0.2.18,10.0.3.18] ---- [10.0.3.15]
                               |
                           box4, www
                           [10.0.2.1]
```

Among other things I want box2 to do nat and port forwarding, so that I can do

```
ssh -p 2223 box2
```

to reach box3. For this I have the following iptables script:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    # flush
    iptables -F INPUT
    iptables -F FORWARD
    iptables -F OUTPUT

    iptables -t nat  -F PREROUTING
    iptables -t nat  -F POSTROUTING
    iptables -t nat  -F OUTPUT

    # default
    default_action=DROP
    for chain in INPUT OUTPUT;do
    iptables -P $chain $default_action
    done
    iptables -P FORWARD DROP


    # allow ssh to local computer
    allowed_ssh_clients="10.0.1.1 10.0.3.15"
    for ip in $allowed_ssh_clients;do
    iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -d $ip -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s $ip -j ACCEPT
    done

    # allow DNS
    iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m state \
    --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -m state \
    --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

    # allow HTTP & HTTPS
    iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp  -m multiport --sports 80,443 -j ACCEPT

    #
    # ROUTING
    #

    # allow routing
    echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    # nat
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

    # http
    iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT

    # ssh redirect
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth1 --dport 2223 -j DNAT \
    --to-destination 10.0.3.15:22
    iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

    iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

    iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --sport 1024:65535 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 1024:65535  -j ACCEPT

    iptables -I FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: "
```

While this works, it takes about 10 seconds to get a password promt from my ssh command. Afterwards, the connection is as responsive as could be. If I change the default policy for my FORWARD chain to "ACCEPT", then the password promt is there imediatly.

I have tried analysing the logs, but I can not spot a difference in the logs for  ACCEPT/DROP in my FORWARD chain. Also I have tried allowing all the unprivileged ports, as box1 uses thoses for doing ssh to box2.

Any hints?

(If the whole setup seems strange to you - the point of the exercise is to understand iptables ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely this is caused by DNS failure in box3. When you change the `FORWARD` policy to `ACCEPT` you are allowing all traffic (include DNS). I can not see any rule allowing DNS traffic in your `FORWARD` chain.

You have two options to speedup ssh login:

1. Allow DNS traffic to pass through your firewall.
2. Configure SSH daemon to not do DNS lookups by changing the line `UseDNS yes` to read `UseDNS no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, adding the following would let DNS pass: iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT. But this did not help

Comment: @Isaac: You need to allow UDP traffic destined to port 53. DNS resolve requests are sent using UDP.

Comment: Thank you Khaled! Of course, DNS uses udp ... working now.